# getops 1 option to receive 2 arguments

Tags: bash, getopts

I've searched around found out that getops receives zero or one argument only, But I really need to make this work,

I need to make my script run like this: ./script.sh -a string integer

What it does is write the string and integer into a text file.

I tried this code:

```
 while getopts a:d opt
 do
 case "$opt" in

 a) na1=$OPTARG
    eval "na2=${OPTIND}"
    shift 2
    ;;

 d) ./viewS.sh;;

 esac
 done

if [ $isdef -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "$na1;$na2" >>PBDB.txt

fi
```

I can write the string part into the text file but the integer just keeps resulting to "3".

sample: ./script.sh -a power 0000

result inside textfile: power;3

any suggestions?

just recently started learning bash scripting

Comment: why on earth do you use the *index* of the argument?

Comment: do you mean the OPTIND ? ..I thought I could make it work that way, I know its not right though..

Comment: What @KarolyHorvath is getting at is that `${OPTIND}` is the next index to be looked at, not the value of that argument. You attempted to fix that with `eval` but missed the extra `\$` necessary. But that's not a good way to do that. Use `${@:$OPTIND:1}` instead. Also I think you are shifting too much there. I think you want `shift` to "swallow" one extra argument. Though personally I think this is a poor design.

Comment: still new to bash scripting :) I learn to make better design in time. thank you for your time sir. I hope I can make this work

Comment: Your code seems to assume `-a` will be used, in which case it isn't an option. Just use positional parameters: `script.sh power 0000` with `na1=$1; na2=$2` inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) tag is accurate (you're not using /bin/sh), change

```
eval "na2=${OPTIND}"
```

to use an "indirect variable"

```
na2=${!OPTIND}
```

With eval, you'd need `eval na2=\$$OPTIND` but that's much uglier

Comment: i just need to make it work. no pro stuff yet. thanks for answering sir

Comment: Uh, not "pro" stuff, just "correct" stuff. What are you objecting to?

Comment: nah.. sorry nvm. thanks for the help sir! it works now